# How to launch a tag when all the triggers have fired in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

You can attach two or more triggers to a tag. They are united with the OR rule, i.e. the tag starts when one of the triggers fires. How to unite the triggers with the AND rule, i.e. make a tag which starts when ALL the given triggers have fired?

Use case: I have a tag that must start when the page DOM is ready and the user location is determined (the location determination starts as soon as possible, before the DOM is ready). I made 2 triggers: «DOM ready» (built-in event) and «Location determined» (custom event fired by a JavaScript code).

P.S. Starting the location determination after the DOM is ready is a workaround, not an answer.

Comment: is firing a custom event an option?

Comment: @ztadic91 Yes. I made the «Location determined» trigger using a custom JavaScript, a custom event and custom variables. The goal is to make a tag start when all the specified triggers have fired.

Comment: Is the "Location determined" reliably set on DOM ready, or is your actual use case that the tag must be fired as soon as "Location determined" is set, but not before the DOM ready event (i.e. "Location determined" might be getting it's value some time after DOM ready) ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff The tag must be fired as soon as "Location determined" is set, but not before the DOM ready event

Answer (score 1):

There is no "and" condition for triggers (and to combine two event based triggers would be impossible, since you cannot evaluate two events at the same time).

The easiest way would be to push a variable to the dataLayer on the "Location determined" event and then have a DOM Ready trigger that fires only when the variable is set (actually you don't event need an event on location determined - if you just push a value it will be accessible on the next event sent to the datalayer, in this case your DOM ready event).

Comment: «you don't event need an event on location determined - if you just push a value it will be accessible on the next event sent to the datalayer, in this case your DOM ready event» — the location can be determined either before or after the DOM is ready.

Comment: «have a DOM Ready trigger that fires only when the variable is set» — how to make a trigger fire only when the variable is set?

Comment: Click "fire on some pageview" and set "if <my variable> does not equal undefined" (or false, or a default value). The problem is of course that if the location services finishes after DOM ready the tag will never be fired - and if  it finished reliably before DOM ready you do not actually need a condition in your DOM ready trigger, because the value will be there in any case.